# Deserializing Jsonobject in mvc webapi

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

Im trying to send a jSon object to a WebApiController and deserialize it to an object but it just gives me an empty object with zero and null.

Id much rather do model binding though but that does not seem to work in Webappi like it does with AJAX call to a normal MVC controller ?

Javascript (jQuery)

```
var data = {
                    siffra : 23,
                    text : "Meddelande från andra sidan!"
                }

                $.ajax({

                    url: "api/Stuff/PostStuff",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log("SUCESS: " + result);
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log("error: " + data.responseText);
                    }
                });
```

WebApiController method

```
 public string PostStuff(JObject jsonObject)
    {
        Stuff stuff  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Stuff>(jsonObject.ToString());
        return "thanks";

    }

    public class Stuff
    {
        public int siffra;
        public string text;     
    }
```

> JObject before deserialization: {"{\"siffra\":23,\"text\":\"Meddelande
>   från andra sidan!\"}": ""}

Comment: Why not just receive a `Stuff` model in the arguments of your action? That way the ModelBinder will deserialise it for you without you needing to do it manually. Also note that you can't return a string from a WebApi action directly.

Comment: Thats What i tried. But it didnt work. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insted of JObject use Stuff model

```
public string PostStuff(Stuff stuff)
{
    return "thanks";

}
```

WebApi should serilize it automaticly.

**Edit**

And make sure that ajax send proper json like this one:

```
{
    "siffra" : 23,
    "text" : "Meddelande från andra sidan!"
}
```

**Edit 2**
Try this call

```
var data = {
                siffra : 23,
                text : "Meddelande från andra sidan!"
            }

            $.ajax({

                url: "api/Stuff/PostStuff",
                method: "POST",
                data: data,
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log("SUCESS: " + result);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log("error: " + data.responseText);
                }
            });
```

Comment: I tried it. Didnt work. Thats why I tried what you see in this post.

Comment: It didin't work because you send wrong objcet.
Make shure that in body of your post is this json:
{
                    "siffra" : 23,
                    "text" : "Meddelande från andra sidan!"
                }

Comment: @Lautaro
Dont use json stringify in data.
Just send data.

Comment: gaaah! That’s what I did before I discovered stringify. Ok I will try. Thanks!

Comment: posibly You will need to add content-type: application/json in request. but i am not sure.

Comment: Yes! This work. And the model binding works only if i remove the contentType : "app/Json". So the model binding works in the simples way. Just create an jsobject in the js and send it without stringify and without stating contentType.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  {"{\"siffra\":23,\"text\":\"Meddelande från andra sidan!\"}": ""}
> ```

That is a JSON object with a single property named `{\"siffra\":23,\"text\":\"Meddelande från andra sidan!\"}` with the empty string for its value. This is nothing like the `Stuff` type.

Which does not match the quoted JS code so you've not included something.

Comment: I have included everything. Check the jQuery. Data : Json.serialize....

Comment: Ive solved it. The ajax request needed a contentType : Json to format properly. Then it works to deserialize like this.